# Unable to receive messages in 2 way client chat via Server using JAVA Sockets.....(MultiThreaded)

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket, event-listener

i am having 2 client sockets..each of them having its own AWT.Frame as GUI for chatting..
On the server side i have a ServerSocket with 2 threads created for handling each of the clients..

The writing of the msg to the stream is done properly but im unable to read it..and both the threads also terminate(i think because of some Exception mostly..NullPointer but isnt shown on the console) after i click "send" button on both the client windows..

Code of ChatServer.main()

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    boolean listening=true;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            server=new ServerSocket(12591);
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Couldn't listen to specified port as it might be already used by some other service");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Waiting for some client to initiate connection...");
        //while (listening)
        //{
            new ChatServerThread(server.accept()).start();
            System.out.println("Connected to User1!");

            new ChatServerThread(server.accept()).start();
            System.out.println("Connected to User2!");
        //}

    }catch(SocketException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    server.close();
}
```

Code of ChatServerThread.constructor() and the run() method(ChatServerThread extends Thread)

```
public ChatServerThread(Socket s)
{
    super("ChatServerThread"+(++count));
    socket = s;

    try
    {
        in=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem getting I/O connection");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            String s = in.readUTF();
            if(s.equals("DISCONNECT~!@#"))
            {
                break;
            }else
            {
                ChatServer.chatMsgs.add(s);
                System.out.println(s);
                //makeClients.c1.display.append(s);
                //makeClients.c2.display.append(s);
                ChatClient.addMsg2Disp(s);
            }
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Methods of ChatClient(has GUI): Its constructor, implemented Listener method:

```
public ChatClient()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    bottomPanel=new Panel(new FlowLayout());
    bottomPanel.add(txtEntry=new TextArea(4,80));
    bottomPanel.add(send=new Button("Send"));
    bottomPanel.add(disconnect=new Button("Disconnect"));

    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    display=new TextArea();
    //display.setEditable(false);
    add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    try
    {
        client=new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12591);
        in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    }catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Local Host cannot be resolved on which the server is runnig");
        System.exit(1);
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem acquiring I/O Connection.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    send.addActionListener(this);
    disconnect.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getSource().equals(send))
    {
        try
        {
            if(!(txtEntry.getText().trim().equals("")))
            {
                out.writeUTF(txtEntry.getText());
                out.flush();
            }
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException occured");
        }
    }
    else if(ae.getSource().equals(disconnect))
    {

    }
}
static void addMsg2Disp(String msg)
{
    display.append(msg);
}
```

and finally there is 1 more class called makeClients which instantiates 2 objs of ChatClient class and sets size, visibility etc of the frame....

i think its a big question but unable to figure out why isnt able to receive..
anyone who could help me out..thanks in advance! :)

PS: and it isnt a real app..i am learning JAVA sockets..so just trying to code something like this..

Comment: Are the clients getting connected to server????What is the output so far?

Comment: @sonuthomas Hmm yes..the 2 SOPln statements that say "Connected" after accepting are being displayed..(thats the output for server side on the console)..

There is no output for console from client as it has only a GUI..so i write some message in a specified textarea..and click send..
after i click send on both the clients the server threads terminate..i dont know why..without any exception..

and the commented out lines for displaying text in `display` textarea gave me `NullPointerException`....so i made textarea static and tried..but now still it doesnt work out..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're problem coule be in your ChatServerThread on this line:

```
if (s.equals("DISCONNECT~!@#") || s != null)
```

The else block will never be executed as `s` can not be `null` (if it is a `NullPointerException` will be thrown when calling the `equals` method on it.  I'm guessing you meant it to be a reference equality check for `null`:

```
if (s.equals("DISCONNECT~!@#") || s == null)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying..! and i think u r right..but that if-else is only meant for checking whether user has requested disconnect or not; and i am not getting a `NullPointerException` over there, i am having it at `ChatClient.addMsg2Disp(s);` statement i.e inside addMsg2Disp method..why is it happening so..

Comment: actually corrected that if-else(i dont know why i had put a !=null check over there)..its just meant for checking disconnect..made a little changes in that if-else and still i have that exception at the place where i append the string to textarea

Comment: Why are you calling a static method on ChatClient from ChatServer?  I'm guessing that's for debugging, but you're not instantiating an instance of ChatClient from within the same JVM as ChatServer.

Comment: Hmm ok..now i get it..and no..that wasnt meant for debugging purpose; what i was trying is that the once the Thread's run method receive any message they call that static method so that it could append the message to the static textarea..so that it is visible to both the clients

Comment: GUI of clients(makeClients class) is executed by a different JVM; not by the same one which executes the ChatServer..thats right....so now what should i do to have messages being appended to textarea..any ideas..?

Comment: Calling a static method of class will only call it in the same JVM, if you want to get data to another JVM you need to use the network stack, which is what you're trying to do here...!  I'll update the answer with some pseudo-code of what you need to do next.

Comment: Hmm ok..will be looking forward to that..!

Answer (score 0):

just a quick fix try

```
if(s != null ? (s.equals("DISCONNECT~!@#")) :false)
```

should solve the NullPointerException problem of yours

Comment: didnt get that..what are you trying to check..1st whether its null or not , and if its null then for equality with disconnect string..?

Comment: My bad, made an edit to the answer,

Heres an explanation of what im trying to do:

First check weather s is not null if so go ahead and perform the s.equals function, else return false.

This only performs the equals function when the value of s is not null, this should solve your NullPointerException problem which is caused when you check for equality with the equals function using a null object

Comment: Hmm ok..even i thought so that you were trying out something like that..anyways i tried out what you said..but still having the same Exception at the point where i try to append the message to the textarea i.e at addMsg2Disp() method call-->inside the method..

Comment: check if s is null before you execute your call to `addMsg2Disp()`, only execute the method call if s is not null. `if(s!=null){ChatClient.addMsg2Disp(s);}`

Comment: `if(s!=null)
    {
     ChatServer.chatMsgs.add(s);
     ChatClient.addMsg2Disp(s);
    }` commented out the whole if-else block and added this..but still it does show the `NullPointerException`

Comment: can you provide us with a stack trace

Comment: Waiting for some client to initiate connection...
hiii
Exception in thread "ChatServerThread2" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ChatClient.addMsg2Disp(ChatClient.java:73)
        at ChatServerThread.run(ChatServerThread.java:44)
hiii
Exception in thread "ChatServerThread1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ChatClient.addMsg2Disp(ChatClient.java:73)
        at ChatServerThread.run(ChatServerThread.java:44)

Comment: this is the output at console for ChatServer..it has the exception stack trace..and `hiii` is the msg that i had written in the text entry..in the clients GUI..and its the actually being received correctly..i.e hiii is the value of variable s....but it isnt able to append it to the textarea..